# Surfaces in $\mathbb P^3$ with many simple isolated singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Could anybody help me with examples of surfaces $X\subset\mathbb P^3$ (projective, over $\mathbb C$) having many isolated singularities of the type $A_1$ ($x^2+y^2+z^2=0$) or $A_2$ ($x^2+y^2+z^3=0$) and no other singular points? «Many» means «as close to the known upper bound (in terms of $\deg X$) as possible».

Thank you in advance,
Serge

Comment: For nodal surfaces, maybe this site would help http://www.oliverlabs.net/view.php?menuitem=168

Comment: What is the known upper bound?

Comment: There is a nice paper by Bruce and Wall that might be of interest to you, in which they classify all possible singularities which may occur for cubic surfaces.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example of an octic with 84 A_2 singularities (known upper bound is 98)
in  arXiv:1108.1820, section 9.

Also, check out this paper
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505022

Answer (score 1):

For the case of surfaces of degree $\le 6$, you may consult 
Catanese, F.; Ceresa, G.: 
J. Pure Appl. Algebra 23 (1982), and, if you read Italian,

Ezio Stagnaro:
Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova 59 (1978), 179–198 (1979).

Octic surfaces with many nodes were constructed  by Marco Kühnel:
Geom. Dedicata 109 (2004), 189–195.